# How to redirect outputs of invoked commands/programs to log4j?

Tags: java, python, linux, logging

I write a program and handle my logs with a logging tool (e.g., Java's `log4j` or Python's `logging`), so all logs produced by myself can go to a log file managed by the logging tool.

I'd also invoke a command or a third party program in my program, which writes all its outputs to the console by default.  How can I redirect those outputs to the log file managed by the logging tool (and make them conform to the logging format if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect all standard output of an external process to a file in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

with open('log', 'ab', 0) as file:
    check_call(['program', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'], stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT)
```

The output is redirected as is. To make it conform to the logging format, you might need it to pass through your program explicitly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

logging.basicConfig(filename='log',level=logging.DEBUG)
with Popen(['program', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1,
           universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        logging.debug('program output %s', line.rstrip('\n'))
```

The code decodes program's standard output using `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` and appends lines to the log file using `logging` module (you could configure whatever logging format you like using standard `logging` tools).

Comment: In Python I'd like to use a rotating file logger in which case I needn't open a file explicitly as *with open('log', 'ab', 0) as file ....* . 
I hope to redirect all outputs of an external process to the logging module and let the logging module do everything for me. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

In java, you could use [IoBuilder](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-iostreams/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/io/IoBuilder.html) from log4j to build your PrintStream. IoBuilder is included in Apache's Log4j Streaming Interface, an addition to Log4J.

Once you have your PrintStream, you can set the system's default PrintStream...

```
 IoBuilder builder = IoBuilder.forLogger(MyClass.class);
 PrintStream myPrintStream = builder.buildPrintStream();
 System.out = myPrintStream;
```

This way, if other library goes `System.out.print()` or `println()` it will be logged through your logger, with your logger format.

Comment: It won't have any effect on the output of an external process ("third party program"). You would need something that redirects at a file descriptor level instead. Here's a [code example in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)